# Linux kernel udp lookup

Tags: c, linux

```
struct sock *udp4_lib_lookup(struct net *net, __be32 saddr, __be16 sport,
                 __be32 daddr, __be16 dport, int dif)
```

Here is declaration of function, that converts connection attributes to `struct sock`. 
As I googled, first argument should be `&init_net`. But what should be last argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dif` argument is the device interface.